# How can I 'hide' a tab in Spotfire depending on the current user in IronPython?

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I have a tab that contains a visualizations for data validation and testing.  I'd like to leave that tab in there without showing to anyone but the devs.

I can get the current user this way but can't find how to 'hide' the tab.

```
from System.Threading import Thread 
print Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm quite sure that hiding a tab is not possible. there are some other possible solutions, though.

1. change the navigation style from **Titled Tabs** to **History Tabs**, then handle navigation between pages with a textarea that is populated by your script. it's the simplest solution, but if you have super sensitive data in this analysis AND your users are accessing via the Analyst client, then a user could change the navigation style.
2. based on the user group, write a script that creates any pages with visualizations on the fly. this one is also at risk to users with Analyst plus scripting access, and is significantly more work to create and maintain (but also really cool and fun, if you like scripting!).
3. make a different analysis per "user group". probably not the best solution since you'd need to repeat any updates for each analysis. this gives you the most security but I think at the highest long-term cost (assuming that the analyses will change over time).

Comment: I confirmed with Tibco that this is not possible via IronPython or JavaScript at this time (6.5).

Answer (score 0):

Update for anyone who may be interested:

In spotfire 10+, you can insert some code into a text area to hide tabs in a dashboard page when viewed on the web (this will not hide tabs on the Analyst client):

```
navigationBar = $("#id10") 
navigationBar.css("display", "none");
```

You can then get fancy with `IPython` to check the user names and add or remove this code from the text area in real time. That will hide and show tabs based on user names.

To show the other tabs, you follow option 1 from niko and just create your own navigation using additional `HTML/CSS` in the text area.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Spotfire 10.8 or higher you have a more robust solution , you can combine below two IronPython scripts into one which is executed on the load of the analysis.

1)Get the username or group
2)Hide the page
3)CustomDateTime Fucntion to trigger IP on load of analysis.

This works for Consumer license  Users.

https://community.tibco.com/wiki/how-fetch-information-about-logged-user-tibco-spotfirer-using-ironpython-script

https://community.tibco.com/wiki/how-show-or-hide-pages-consumer-users-viewing-mode-tibco-spotfirer-using-ironpython-script

https://community.tibco.com/wiki/custom-datetime-data-function-tibco-spotfire

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.